# worklight 5.0.6 JsonRestStore, use of Promises

Tags: jquery, ibm-mobilefirst, deferred, jsonstore

This was originally a question about the Worklight documentation, it transpires that my real question is about JQuery's Deferred/Promise API and the promise.then() function.

Context:

The documentation for the [5.0.6 JsonRestStore API](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_initcollection.html) gives examples of using the new Promise capability offering two possible formulations.

```
someFunction.then( 
             successCallback,
             errorCallback,
             optionalProgressCallback);
```

And

```
 someFunction().then(successCallback).fail(errorCallback)
```

These two approaches seem, as comments and answers state, effectively the same.

My puzzle is that the [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) states that then() returns a "new promise".

hence in the second case we are coding:

```
  var p1 = someFunction();
  var p2 = p1.then(successCallback);
  p2.fail(errorCallback);
```

I've also seen folks set up a "chain" of actions like this:

```
  someFunction().then(action2).then(action3).then(action4);
```

setting up a chain of asynchronous actions. So my question becomes what is the relationship between the promises p1 and p2 in the example above. How does that relate to the chain idea?

--- edited to reference the answer ---

Thanks to cnandreu: the key point is that "errors are propagated down a promise chain until an error handler is found." The answer is [explained nicely here](http://blog.parse.com/2013/01/29/whats-so-great-about-javascript-promises/).

Comment: Both pieces of code do the same.

Comment: @Manolo, functionally I agree, it works. But what's actually going on? Somehow p1.then(good, error), which is the same as p1.fail(error) and p2.fail(error) are having the same effect, p1 and p2 are clearly related - how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var p1 = someFunction();
var p2 = p1.then(successCallback);
p2.fail(errorCallback);
```

> So my question becomes what is the relationship between the promises
>   p1 and p2 in the example above. How does that relate to the chain
>   idea?

Promises are a way of handling asynchronous code, here's a [quick video](https://tutsplus.com/lesson/deferreds/) and [article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/wrangle-async-tasks-with-jquery-promises/) that explains them. `someFunction()` is going to do an async task, when it finishes it (i.e. gets [resolved](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/)) it executes the `successCallback` and if that fails (ie. is [rejected](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/)) it executes the `errorCallback`. The relationship is that `p2` is a promise that will get executed only when `p1` gets [rejected](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.reject/). Think of `p1.then(win, fail)` and `p1.then(win).fail(fail)` as two ways of writing the same thing.

The original question was probably referring to the following:

> A promise object is returned after a JSONStore asynchronous operation
>   is called (find, add, remove, and so on). [...] The [JSONStore.add, JSONStore.find, etc.] failure callback,
>   passed as either the second parameter of .then or the first parameter
>   of .fail returns an error object, [...]

from the [JSONStore Documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_class_wl_jsonstore.html). The documentation is specific to the JSONStore API, we refer readers to the jQuery documentation to learn about how promises work in general (*see jQuery's API documentation for more details.*).

Here's an example:

```
var collections = {
        people : {
            searchFields : {name: 'THIS_SHOULD_PRODUCE_AN_ERROR'}
        }
    };

WL.JSONStore.init(collections)

.then(function(res){
    //the code here should not be called because we expect to fail
    console.log(typeof res === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(res) : res);
})

.fail(function(err){
    console.log(err.toString());
});
```

The output is:

```
{"src":"initCollection","err":-12,"msg":"INVALID_SEARCH_FIELD_TYPES","col":"people","usr":"jsonstore","doc":{},"res":{}}
```

If we switch to `.then(success, failure)`:

```
var collections = {
        people : {
            searchFields : {name: 'THIS_SHOULD_PRODUCE_AN_ERROR'}
        }
    };

var success = function(res){
    //the code here should not be called because we expect to fail
    console.log(typeof res === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(res) : res);
};

var failure = function(err){
    console.log(err.toString());
};

WL.JSONStore.init(collections).then(success, failure);
```

We get the same output:

```
{"src":"initCollection","err":-12,"msg":"INVALID_SEARCH_FIELD_TYPES","col":"people","usr":"jsonstore","doc":{},"res":{}}
```

Mix them, pick one or use the deprecated callbacks. All JSONStore examples in the documentation should work as expected. Please update your question with real citations from the documentations and a real example showing that the documentation is wrong and I will update my answer. If it turns out something *is* wrong, I will do everything possible to fix it.

Comment: Thanks, I agree that the WL docs are fine, my mistake in understanding then(). Adjusted question accordingly.

Comment: Not sure if it's what you're looking for, but I updated my answer.

Comment: So close ... the point is that p1.then(good, fail) relates to p1. We are effectively writing p1.fail().  But p1.then() returns a new promise: p2. and when we write p1.then().fail() we are effectively writing p2.fail() not p1.fail(), and yet it all just works. Somehow p2.fail() and p1.fail() are having the same effect even though they are separate promises (I assume that they are not really "separate" - but I can't interpret what's happening,)

Comment: I think [this article](http://blog.parse.com/2013/01/29/whats-so-great-about-javascript-promises/) could be helpful. Under 'Error Handling': "Because promises know whether they’ve been fulfilled or failed, they can propagate errors, not calling any callback until an error handler is encountered."

Comment: Yep that's the key missing piece in my understanding. Thanks very much for finding that.

Answer (score 0):

They are functionally the same, this is basically how chaining works right? You have 2 choices, either take the output of one call, and chain it to the next call, or you can save the result in a named variable, and then call the next operation on that named variable.

```
var str = "   fooo ";
str.trim().indexOf('f');
```

versus

```
var str = "   fooo ";
var strTrimmed = str.trim()
strTrimmed.indexOf('f');
```

Comment: But that's the point, you do have two different strings there: str and strTrimmed. When we do xxx().then().fail() we have two apparently separate promises: p1 returned by xxx() and p2 returned by then(). If we code p1.then(good, bad) we are associating bad with p1. if we code p1.then(good).fail(bad) we are assoiating bad with p2. And yet somehow it has the same effect.