# Worklight Procedure invocation error. Illegal Argument invalid type of element

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I am trying to push JSONStore record to my MySql database via a SqlAdapter. Im getting following error.

> Procedure invocation error. Illegal Argument: invalid type of element
>
> 12 Error Message: ADAPTER_FAILURE

When this error comes. I have done everything as per the docs.

So far what I have done is,

My DB table structure is like this,

> ```
> > emp_id | emp_name | emp_address
> > -------------------------------
> ```

Create a JSONStore collection and it displays all records, 
adds new record to the collection but issue happens when I push it to server here's my code

Collection :-

```
var resultSet = WL.JSONStore.initCollection("resultSet",
        {"emp_id":"integer","emp_name":"string","emp_address":"string"},
```

For pushing record to  DB server,

```
WLJQ('[data-role="button"]#push_selected').bind('click', function () {

                WL.Logger.debug('Called button#push_selected');
                if (!checkColInit(resultSet)) {return;}
                    var id=idTag.val();
                    if(id.length<1)
                        {
                        logMessage("You must provide a valid id");
                        }
                    else{
                    var win =   function (data) {
                        logMessage("Successfully Pushed selected Documents : " + data );
                        idTag.val("");
                    };
                    var options = {onSuccess: win, onFailure: genericFailureCallback};
                    var doc=WL.JSONStore.documentify(parseInt(id),{emp_id:id,emp_name: "James", emp_address:"NY"});
                    resultSet.pushSelected(doc,options);
            }
            });
```

Comment: @Idan Adar Any solutions to my problem?

Comment: It would help to see what you're passing, as can be seen by the invocation error - invalid type of element... Edit the question with this information.

Answer (score 1):

**ADAPTER_FAILURE**: Problem calling `WL.Client.invokeProcedure`, specifically a problem in connecting to the Worklight server adapter.

For [push](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_push.html) you need to tell the JSONStore collection the adapter name and the procedures to call when you add, replace or delete data. If you're using [load](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_load.html), you also need to specify the procedure name to get the data, any parameters you want to pass the adapter and a key that points to the array of objects or the object you want to store inside your JSONStore collection.

I go into a bit more detail on how to get data from an adapter to a collection, and send data from a collection to adapter in my answer to: [IBM Worklight JSON Store with Sync using HTTP Adapater](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16823548/186909).

I see you're using [initCollection](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_initcollection.html), I highly recommend using [init](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_init.html) instead. I also recommend you use promises (read about them in the [documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_class_wl_jsonstore.html), I also answered a question about promises and JSONStore [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16048737/186909)) instead of the callbacks you're using now (`onSuccess` and `onFailure`).

I would also [discourage you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15924175/186909) from using jQuery's `bind` function, try the [on function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

I posted an answer with tips on how to debug JSONStore if you run into issues, you can read it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15959984/186909).